# how to convert a java project to a jar file

Tags: java, jar, command-prompt

I created a java project using netbeansIDE. Now I want to convert it into an .exe file, but I need to convert the java project into a .jar file first, since java project can't be compiled into a .exe file directly it can be only be converted to exe from jar file. So how shall I convert java project into a .jar file. Please answer in detail since I am a beginer in java programing.

Thank You.

Comment: See https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html

Comment: `JavaScript != Java` :)

Comment: go to the directory that contains all your code.(via cmd)

then type- jar cf name.jar *.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Netbeans IDE then you can easily build a jar file of your project.
Just go to Run in the Menu above and select clean and build.
Now goto to you project folder, find Dist folder inside it and there you have your .jar file.